# How to see webpage code if it does not let me right click on it and inspect?

Tags: javascript, right-click, web-inspector, inspect, google-developer-tools

[this JS alchemy game](https://littlealchemy.com/) is what i want to copy, it s open source and has its code on [github](https://github.com/alancnet/little-alchemy).

However, I want to see its code on webpage, right clicking when playing does not show context menu, I can not do "inspect source".

How do I inspect the actual html code?

Comment: Use Web developer toolbar in Chrome or Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMD+ALT+I in chrome would open inspector.